# VueRouter route should select first child by default

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Hi everyone i'm using Vue-Router 2.5.3 and i have the following Route structure.

```
 path: "/admin", component: require("./views/layouts/MasterLayout.vue"), meta: { requiresAuth: true }, children: [
                { path: 'dashboard', component: require("./views/Dashboard.vue"), alias: "/", name: "dashboard" },

                { path: 'upload', component: require("./views/Upload.vue"), name: "upload", redirect: {name: 'upload.photo'}, children: [

                    {
                        path: 'photo',
                        component: require("./components/Uploaders/ImagesUploader.vue"),
                        name: "upload.photo",
                        props: { selected: true, successEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload/complete", uploadEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload" }
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'video',
                        component: require("./components/Uploaders/VideoUploader.vue"),
                        name: "upload.video",
                        props: { selected: true, successEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload/complete", uploadEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload" }
                    }

                ] },
```

And i have an issue with this configuration, whenever i navigate to "admin/upload" it shows a blank page, i want it to show "admin/upload/photo" by default even if my users navigate to "admin/upload" how can i acheive this in Vue Router?

I've already tried defining aliases in both "upload" and in the child routes and nothing happened, then i tried to define the **redirect** key in the "upload" parent route as well and again blank page...

I don't quite get what im going wrong, is it the fact that my structure has two levels of nesting? But if that's a problem how do i define these routes using only one level of nesting?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind everyone, somewhat dumb question... (having a bad day at the office today)

Just add

```
alias: "/"
```

to the child route you want to use as default...

So in my case "photo" might become

```
 { 
    path: 'photo',
    component: require("./components/Uploaders/ImagesUploader.vue"),
    name: "upload.photo",
    alias: "/",
    props: { selected: true, successEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload/complete", uploadEndpoint: "/api/v1/upload" }
 },
```

Because what we want is for "photo" to respond to the root within "upload" so we tell it to respond to both upload/"photo" and to upload"/" because these are nested inside "upload" the "upload" route is always prepended to any child and it's aliases.